# Spoofing UserAgent in Opera

Tags: ipad, opera, spoofing

I'm trying to spoof Opera (under Linux) to be another browser, in this case iPad for some testing purposes.
Now I know sites can check which browser is accessing it using, for example, in PHP `$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` and in JavaScript `navigator.userAgent` (or `navigator.platform`).

In Firefox you can use an addon to easily switch your user agent and other relevant information, but in Opera it seems it bit hard to do.

First in `opera.ini` you can do:

```
[User Agent]
Spoof UserAgent ID=1
```

But this is limited to a predefined list of UserAgents. No room for custom ones.

Also in `opera.ini`

```
[ISP]
Id=iPad
```

This will add iPad to the User Agent of Opera. It's a start and works most of the time on the sites.

In `opera.ini` you can set a 'User JavaScript file' to load a custom JavaScript file before loading a website:

```
[User Prefs]
User JavaScript File=/opera_dir/userjs/load.js
```

In `load.js` you can do:

```
navigator.userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.10"
```

Because this file gets executed before loading the website I can modify the UserAgent, but this won't work when a site is checking the UserAgent via PHP, but it works for sites checking with JavaScript.

Is there another way of spoofing a complete custom UserAgent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. In desktop Opera, that is.

Some custom ("GOGI"-type) developer builds found on http://labs.opera.com might offer the **opera:config#UserPrefs|CustomUser-Agent** option where you can specify the entire UA string (the builds that were released a while back are rather old by now). Perhaps you'd be better of with the device SDK tools? Have a look at http://dev.opera.com/sdk/

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish the same feat using a web-proxy. I'll recommend to try out
[Charles Web Debugging Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/). From the charles proxy introduction:

> Charles is an HTTP proxy / HTTP
>   monitor / Reverse Proxy that enables a
>   developer to view all of the HTTP and
>   SSL / HTTPS traffic between their
>   machine and the Internet. This
>   includes requests, responses and the
>   HTTP headers (which contain the
>   cookies and caching information).

Comment: True, but this requires an additional program. Which is unwanted in this case. This is for a browser in a consumer electronics device.